# wix-events-backend createEvent() code failing on eventInfo

Tags: javascript, backend, velo

Trying to get programmatic Event creation in place for Wix Events.

Followed the steps detailed here:
https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/wix-events-backend/wixevents/createevent

i.e,

```
import { wixEvents } from "wix-events-backend";

const eventInfo = {
  title: "Healthy Living Series: Exercise and You",
  location: {
    name: "Community Hall",
    address: {
      formatted: "100 Gansevoort St, New York, NY 10014, USA",
      city: "New York City",
      subdivision: "New York",
      country: "USA",
      postalCode: "10014",
      streetAddress: {
        number: "100",
        name: "Gansevoort Street",
        apt: "10"
      }
    },
    type: 'VENUE',
  },
  scheduling: {
    startDate: "2021-09-14T13:30:00.000Z",
    endDate: "2021-09-14T15:30:00.000Z",
    timeZoneId: "America/New_York"
  },
  registration: {
    initialType: 'RSVP'
  }
};

const options = {
  language: "en"
};

export function myCreateEventFunction() {
  return wixEvents.createEvent(eventInfo, options)
    .then((result) => {
      return result;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
}
```

The code snippet provided is failing with this error on the eventInfo parameter:
[image: wix createEvent() eventinfo error]

```
Argument of type '{ title: any; description: any; about: any; location: { name: any; address: { formatted: any; city: any; subdivision: any; country: any; postalCode: any; streetAddress: { number: string; name: string; apt: string; }; }; type: string; }; scheduling: { ...; }; registration: { ...; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'WixEventInfo'. Type '{ title: any; description: any; about: any; location: { name: any; address: { formatted: any; city: any; subdivision: any; country: any; postalCode: any; streetAddress: { number: string; name: string; apt: string; }; }; type: string; }; scheduling: { ...; }; registration: { ...; }; }' is missing the following properties from type 'WixEventInfo': locationInfo, schedulingInfo
```

Anyone have any clues how to get past this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw the same error in the editor, but if you actually run the code you may get different errors, delivered via the .catch((error) to the console.log.

I was able to create an event with the test code by
a) changing the incorrect location country field from

```
    country: "USA",
```

to

```
    country: "US",
```

b) removing the scheduling field start and end dates and using TBD instead:

```
  scheduling: {
    tbd: true,
    tbdMessage: "pending my dates",
    timeZoneId: "EST"
  }
```

I tried lots of different formats for start and end dates, but could not get any of them to work, including the ones in the example

```
    startDate: "2021-09-14T13:30:00.000Z",
    endDate: "2021-09-14T15:30:00.000Z",
```

The Wix documentation doesnt help much either, for example when defining the input parameter eventInfo  - it says the structure contains an object with Name "schedulingInfo" but that is not correct, it has to be "scheduling"; strangely if you change that in your code to schedulingInfo (as well as location to locationInfo), you dont get the static error you have posted, but you do get a run-time error.

I am going to raise this in the Forums in Wix so watch out for that.

Comment: I found the answer. As the API documentation states, the startDate and endDate fields are of type Date, so the example code is incorrect.

You need to do something like this:
  scheduling: {
        timeZoneId: "Europe/London",
 startDate: new Date("2021-09-25T12:00:00Z"),
 endDate: new Date("2021-09-26T12:00:00Z")
 },

Comment: Awesomeee! Just got a chance to try this out and, although the same error message was showing up in the WIX editor (obviously a bug), I published anyways, and verified it's working as expected with your suggested changes. Thanks man!!